# Express parameterized route conflict

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I have two routes in Express 4.13 app:

```
router.get('/:id', function (req, res) {
});

router.get('/new', function(req,res){
});
```

But when I'm trying to access `/new` - I get 404, because there is no 'new' object. So how can I change set up that I can access /new route without confusion with /:id route.

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to add a function to check the parameter and place `/new` router before `/:id`:

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    r = express.Router();

r.param('id', function( req, res, next, id ) {
    req.id_from_param = id;
    next();
});

r.get("/new", function( req, res ) {
  res.send('some new');
});

// route to trigger the capture
r.get('/:id', function (req, res) {
  res.send( "ID: " + req.id_from_param );
})

app.use(r);

app.listen(3000, function () { })
```

Comment: Thank a lot. Placing /new before /:id solved my problem. I'll remember that order makes big sense.

Comment: Glad I saw your answer.

Comment: I'm not a node expert and this answer saved my day!

Comment: Still works after 8 years :D and same conflict exists

Comment: Switch to Spring Boot!

Answer (score 46):

Do it like this . Dynamic api should be on bottom

```
router.get('/new', function(req,res){
});

router.get('/:id', function (req, res) {
});
```

[image: A very simple example with test]

Comment: Simply moving the dynamic api methods below the static ones fixed my issues. Thanks!

Comment: I have one question though: what happens if I have a middleware after both routes? Does next() call the next handler or the handler that causes the conflict?